# C# - Transmit voice over packets

Tags: c#

I created a simple server-client chat application which uses packets (and a buffer). For the messages I use "WriteString" which writes it to the binWriter and sends it to the clients.

Has it done before? I want to transmit the client's microphone output through the packets and be able to hear them through all the clients. How can I do that? Do you guys have any example?

This is my Packet class.

```
 public class Packet
{
    private MemoryStream _memoryStream;
    private BinaryReader _binReader;
    private BinaryWriter _binWriter;

    public Packet(byte[] pData)
    {
        _memoryStream = new MemoryStream(pData);
        _binReader = new BinaryReader(_memoryStream);
    }

    public Packet()
    {
        _memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        _binWriter = new BinaryWriter(_memoryStream);
    }

    public Packet(byte pOpcode)
    {
        _memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        _binWriter = new BinaryWriter(_memoryStream);
        WriteByte(pOpcode);
    }

    public byte[] ToArray()
    {
        return _memoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    public int Length
    {
        get { return (int)_memoryStream.Length; }
    }

    public int Position
    {
        get { return (int)_memoryStream.Position; }
        set { _memoryStream.Position = value; }
    }

    public void Reset(int pPosition = 0)
    {
        _memoryStream.Position = pPosition;
    }

    public void Skip(int pAmount)
    {
        if (pAmount + _memoryStream.Position > Length)
            throw new Exception("!!! Cannot skip more bytes than there's inside the buffer!");
        _memoryStream.Position += pAmount;
    }

    public byte[] ReadLeftoverBytes()
    {
        return ReadBytes(Length - (int)_memoryStream.Position);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string ret = "";
        foreach (byte b in ToArray())
        {
            ret += string.Format("{0:X2} ", b);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public void WriteBytes(byte[] val) { _binWriter.Write(val); }
    public void WriteByte(byte val) { _binWriter.Write(val); }
    public void WriteSByte(sbyte val) { _binWriter.Write(val); }
    public void WriteBool(bool val) { WriteByte(val == true ? (byte)1 : (byte)0); }
    public void WriteShort(short val) { _binWriter.Write(val); }
    public void WriteInt(int val) { _binWriter.Write(val); }
    public void WriteLong(long val) { _binWriter.Write(val); }
    public void WriteUShort(ushort val) { _binWriter.Write(val); }
    public void WriteUInt(uint val) { _binWriter.Write(val); }
    public void WriteULong(ulong val) { _binWriter.Write(val); }
    public void WriteDouble(double val) { _binWriter.Write(val); }
    public void WriteFloat(float val) { _binWriter.Write(val); }
    public void WriteString(string val) { WriteShort((short)val.Length); _binWriter.Write(val.ToCharArray()); }
    public void WriteString(string val, int maxlen) { var i = 0; for (; i < val.Length & i < maxlen; i++) _binWriter.Write(val[i]); for (; i < maxlen; i++) WriteByte(0); }
    public void WriteMapleString(string val) { WriteShort((short)val.Length); _binWriter.Write(val.ToCharArray()); }

    public void WriteHexString(string pInput)
    {
        pInput = pInput.Replace(" ", "");
        if (pInput.Length % 2 != 0) throw new Exception("Hex String is incorrect (size)");
        for (int i = 0; i < pInput.Length; i += 2)
        {
            WriteByte(byte.Parse(pInput.Substring(i, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
        }

    }

    public byte[] ReadBytes(int pLen) { return _binReader.ReadBytes(pLen); }
    public bool ReadBool() { return _binReader.ReadByte() != 0; }
    public byte ReadByte() { return _binReader.ReadByte(); }
    public sbyte ReadSByte() { return _binReader.ReadSByte(); }
    public short ReadShort() { return _binReader.ReadInt16(); }
    public int ReadInt() { return _binReader.ReadInt32(); }
    public long ReadLong() { return _binReader.ReadInt64(); }
    public ushort ReadUShort() { return _binReader.ReadUInt16(); }
    public uint ReadUInt() { return _binReader.ReadUInt32(); }
    public ulong ReadULong() { return _binReader.ReadUInt64(); }
    public double ReadDouble() { return _binReader.ReadDouble(); }
    public float ReadFloat() { return _binReader.ReadSingle(); }
    public string ReadString(short pLen = -1) { short len = pLen == -1 ? _binReader.ReadInt16() : pLen; return new string(_binReader.ReadChars(len)); }

    public void SetBytes(int pPosition, byte[] val) { int tmp = (int)_memoryStream.Position; Reset(pPosition); _binWriter.Write(val); Reset(tmp); }
    public void SetByte(int pPosition, byte val) { int tmp = (int)_memoryStream.Position; Reset(pPosition); _binWriter.Write(val); Reset(tmp); }
    public void SetSByte(int pPosition, sbyte val) { int tmp = (int)_memoryStream.Position; Reset(pPosition); _binWriter.Write(val); Reset(tmp); }
    public void SetBool(int pPosition, bool val) { int tmp = (int)_memoryStream.Position; Reset(pPosition); WriteByte(val == true ? (byte)1 : (byte)0); Reset(tmp); }
    public void SetShort(int pPosition, short val) { int tmp = (int)_memoryStream.Position; Reset(pPosition); _binWriter.Write(val); Reset(tmp); }
    public void SetInt(int pPosition, int val) { int tmp = (int)_memoryStream.Position; Reset(pPosition); _binWriter.Write(val); Reset(tmp); }
    public void SetLong(int pPosition, long val) { int tmp = (int)_memoryStream.Position; Reset(pPosition); _binWriter.Write(val); Reset(tmp); }
    public void SetUShort(int pPosition, ushort val) { int tmp = (int)_memoryStream.Position; Reset(pPosition); _binWriter.Write(val); Reset(tmp); }
    public void SetUInt(int pPosition, uint val) { int tmp = (int)_memoryStream.Position; Reset(pPosition); _binWriter.Write(val); Reset(tmp); }
    public void SetULong(int pPosition, ulong val) { int tmp = (int)_memoryStream.Position; Reset(pPosition); _binWriter.Write(val); Reset(tmp); }
}
```

Comment: real-time voice and video streaming almost exclusively uses UDP rather than TCP, as far as I'm aware.  TCP is designed for guaranteed data integrity, which you don't need for media streaming, and as such TCP is often too slow, laggy, and unresponsive for real-time streaming.  If TCP drops a packet it tries to re-transmit until it succeeds.  UDP doesn't care, it just keeps going - you get an artifact in the media stream, but it doesn't stop.  I would look into working with UDP as a first step.  You should find lots of examples with a search.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this library : http://nspeex.codeplex.com/documentation

It has been made to encode and decode the voice.

J... was right about udp : better to use for voip